# Animated cell reordering in an NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, macos

Is there a good technique or example code demonstrating how to implement animated cell reordering? I have a custom cell class and regular reordering works fine, but I'd like to animate as much of it as possible (preferable something like the tab reordering in safari except in a tableview).

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There was a "Cocoa Tips and Tricks" session at WWDC 04 where Apple demoed exactly that behaviour, however I haven't been able to find it online.

[This 2004 cocoa-dev post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2004/1/13/98815) hints that Dan Wood (of Karelia) has implemented that effect for a MacTech article, code on [Dan's site](http://gigliwood.com/tabletester/).

Comment: I've seen Dan's code - It is for sorting, and doesn't really help me implement animated reordering. I've been told the best way is to write a custom table component using Core Animation to get any animation I want for free... so I may end up doing that.